# TypeError at /facebook/connect/ when using Django Facebook

Tags: python, django, facebook

I am trying to use Django Facebook from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-facebook/6.0.2 with Django 1.7.

I have registered an App with Facebook and configured Django Facebook with the App ID and secret.  When I go to the "http://127.0.0.1:8000/facebook/example/" URL from my local site I get the test page.  Then when I click "Log in with Facebook" I get the error:

```
TypeError at /facebook/connect/
Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/facebook/connect/?
attempt=1&code=AQD2ZiACodQPqMeD5Z9eO2kvHBc__LPMz72A9puFad5I50b-wh-
WwKJWcYabOfjEj-2R1-4gOxkLHi8HnF1A9lwdEAkS26-AmI4ZpzkYt-
2NY6DYSTRxwdNdFy15CSZ3Uo1MntWtuyOotC9S_lkCSJ8nPa4AjK4YG2Tny-
aZ84ZGKtMnJez1nQN2Onx39u5ONdooQhCo6kmSml-
OvenK_iJ2tXQoXZOoQjTqX9bCcF5expDfHDq1lihax-bIloMfDVvStypOxLB27moZKg-
LCP3VhjY8QLa0kIvmR2VdRvBZZVjui1dJ6xGtj0YvrzYxlFr3_pYFkZyz5W32qyONgZTt
Django Version: 1.7.7
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
Exception Location: C:\landy\lib\site-packages\django_facebook\utils.py in    
hash_key, line 153
Python Executable:  C:\landy\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.4.2
Python Path:    
['C:\\landy\\mobile',
 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python34.zip',
 'C:\\Python34\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python34\\lib',
 'C:\\Python34',
 'C:\\landy',
 'C:\\landy\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 8 May 2015 18:25:02 +0000
```

Here is my traceback:

```
C:\landy\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, 
**callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\landy\lib\site-packages\django\db\transaction.py in inner
            return func(*args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\landy\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\landy\lib\site-packages\django_facebook\decorators.py in wrapped_view
        response = self.authenticate(self.fn, request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\landy\lib\site-packages\django_facebook\decorators.py in authenticate
            request, redirect_uri=redirect_uri) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\landy\lib\site-packages\django_facebook\api.py in 
require_persistent_graph
graph = get_persistent_graph(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\landy\lib\site-packages\django_facebook\api.py in get_persistent_graph
    graph = get_facebook_graph(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\landy\lib\site-packages\django_facebook\api.py in get_facebook_graph
            cache_key = hash_key('convert_code_%s' % code) ...
▶ Local vars
C:\landy\lib\site-packages\django_facebook\utils.py in hash_key
hashed = hashlib.md5(key).hexdigest() ...
▶ Local vars
```

I don't know what is going on.

Comment: Does Django Facebook even work? The build has been failing for a long time https://travis-ci.org/tschellenbach/Django-facebook/builds .

Comment: What are the alternatives?

Comment: I don't know, I don't work with this stuff. But perhaps try to find a known good, i.e. older version of Django-Facebook and Django. Or you have to fix it yourself. The issue might be that Facebook is constantly changing.